# C# app.config file

Tags: c#, app-config

this is my code...

```
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
    AppSettingsSection configSection = config.AppSettings;

    try
    {
        if (configSection != null)
        {
            if (configSection.IsReadOnly() == false && configSection.SectionInformation.IsLocked == false)
            {
                configSection.Settings["DailyFilName"].Value = "NewValue";
                config.Save();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ConfigurationException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Configuration Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

But its not update my config file :(

Comment: We are not compilers to read your code and understand how it will compile/run. Little more explanation would help you and us ;-)

Comment: what is the scope of the configuration values?

Comment: Exception or some more info would be helpful indeed. Wildguess, did you misspell 'DailyFilName'?

Answer (score 1):

you should use this :

```
configSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

take a look at the ConfigurationSaveMode enum for more options

Comment: also, just noticed the name of the settings is not written correctly "DailyFilName". perhaps a typo here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution from the article [How to change App.config file run time using C#](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/how-to-change-appconfig-file-run-time-using-c/)

```
 // Open App.Config of executable

 System.Configuration.Configuration config = 
 ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

 // Add an Application Setting.

 config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("LastDateFeesChecked");

 config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("LastDateFeesChecked",    
 DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

 // Save the configuration file.

 config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

 // Force a reload of a changed section.

ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: Verbatim unattributed copy from http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/how-to-change-appconfig-file-run-time-using-c/

Answer (score 0):

replace config.Save();

to be

```
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be you don't have your configuration parameters as "user-scoped"